# need help creating a dynamic columned table

Tags: tables

```
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{>{\SplitList{;}}m}
{
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ \ProcessList{#1} c}
        \ProcessList{#1}{\additem}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}}
}

  \newcommand\additem[1]{#1 &}
```

Im trying to make a dynamic table that will take in as many args in the list and out put to the table with each item being a column.. having an issue with the number of columns and the number of & being inserted. any help would be greatly appreciated.

my issue is with predicting the number of columns in the table. and preventing the

`! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\ProcessList):`c' used.`

or if i remove the processlist  i get

`! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Real quick: Assuming you have a rough idea what the maximum possible number of columns in a `tabular` environment could be (say, 10), could you just specify something like `\begin{tabular}{*{20}{c}}`?  Nothing bad will happen if you end up providing entries for fewer than 20 columns.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what this command would do, since a one row tabular is just a single line and so `tabular` is not needed at all: you'd get the required behavior by simply saying

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{>{\SplitList{;}}m}{%
  \begin{table}
  \centering
  \ProcessList{#1}{\additem}
  \end{table}
}

\newcommand{\additem}[1]{\mbox{\hspace{\tabcolsep}#1\hspace{\tabcolsep}}}
```

Complete example, with the same table typeset explicitly, in order to see that the output is exactly the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{>{\SplitList{;}}m}{%
  \begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \ProcessList{#1}{\additem}
  \end{table}
}

\newcommand{\additem}[1]{\mbox{\hspace{\tabcolsep}#1\hspace{\tabcolsep}}}

\begin{document}

\foo{abc;def;ghijkl;m}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
abc & def & ghijkl & m
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a more useful macro, here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
  \bob_make_table:n { #1 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_bob_colcount_int
\seq_new:N \l_bob_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l_bob_temp_seq
\tl_new:N \l_bob_table_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \bob_make_table:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_bob_rows_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \int_zero:N \l_bob_colcount_int
  % count the number of columns
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_bob_rows_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_bob_temp_seq { ; } { ##1 }
    \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l_bob_temp_seq > \l_bob_colcount_int }
     {
      \int_set:Nn \l_bob_colcount_int { \seq_count:N \l_bob_temp_seq }
     }
   }
  % produce the table
  \tl_set:Nn \l_bob_table_tl { \begin{tabular}{*{\l_bob_colcount_int}{c}} }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_bob_rows_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_bob_temp_seq { ; } { ##1 }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_bob_table_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_bob_temp_seq { & } }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_bob_table_tl { \\ }
   }
  % print the table
  \tl_use:N \l_bob_table_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\foo{
  abc;def\\
  ghijkl;m;nopqrs;tu\\
  vz
}

\end{document}
```

Rows are separated by `\\` and columns by `;`.

[image]